# facebbook feed dialog params in a android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am giving a picture url http://graph.facebook.com/User_Id/picture as params to facebook feed dialog where user_id is the username of particular user on facebook. But it's showing an error on android that "FBCDN image not allowed in facebook stream". So, anybody know how to give picture from a profile on facebook???

Also how to make this picture attatch to a link that opens particular user profile on facebook or to link this picture to any url ????

Here is the code that i am using to give params to facebook feed dialog.

```
//Giving the params to feed dialog
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", facebookMessage);
params.putString("link", ComLabelConstants.FACEBOOK_LINK);
params.putString("name", linkname);
params.putString("picture", "http://graph.facebook.com/XXXX/picture");
params.putString("caption", ComLabelConstants.FACEBOOK_LINK_CAPTION);
params.putString("description", "This is description");

// displaying facebook dialogs
mFacebook.dialog(FbookAlertBoxActivity.this, "feed", params,
    new SampleDialogListener(this, mAsyncRunner));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I have researched...facebook doesn't allow it's domain image to be posted on wall through post. So, we can't use it. Now what I am doing is getting the imge through following code:

```
ImageView user_picture;
        user_picture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.user_picture);
        URL img_value = null;
        Bitmap mIcon1 = null;
        try {
            img_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/XXXX/picture");
            try {
                mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_value
                        .openConnection().getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(mIcon1!=null){
            user_picture.setImageBitmap(mIcon1);
        }
```

if you want it to convert to byte array

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();   
        mIcon1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);    
        b = baos.toByteArray();
```

Sending this image to my server and then posting to wall.